# firebase init gives EPROTO error

Tags: firebase

Running firebase init command gives an EPROTO error.  Same error when I try firebase list.  I can successfully use firebase login though.  Here is the output of the firebase.debug.log:

```
[debug]  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug]  Command:       C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\andre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\bin\firebase init
[debug]  CLI Version:   3.13.1
[debug]  Platform:      win32
[debug]  Node Version:  v8.8.1
[debug]  Time:          Sat Oct 28 2017 12:35:18 GMT+0100 (GMT Summer Time)
[debug]  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] 
[debug]  > command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase"]
[debug] [2017-10-28T11:35:18.899Z] > authorizing via signed-in user
You're about to initialize a Firebase project in this directory:

  C:\Users\andre\Documents\cake-poly20-test

[info] 
=== Project Setup
[info] 
[info] First, let's associate this project directory with a Firebase project.
[info] You can create multiple project aliases by running firebase use --add, 
[info] but for now we'll just set up a default project.
[info] 
[debug]  > refreshing access token with scopes: ["email","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","openid"]
[debug]  >>> HTTP REQUEST POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token { refresh_token: '<token>',
  client_id: '<clientid>.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  client_secret: '<secret>',
  grant_type: 'refresh_token',
  scope: 'email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase openid' } 
 Sat Oct 28 2017 12:35:25 GMT+0100 (GMT Summer Time)
[debug]  <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[debug]  >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://admin.firebase.com/v1/projects  
 Sat Oct 28 2017 12:35:25 GMT+0100 (GMT Summer Time)
[debug]  Error: write EPROTO 101057795:error:140773E8:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:reason(1000):openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:772:

    at _errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
    at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:870:14)
[error] 
[error] Error: Server Error. write EPROTO 101057795:error:140773E8:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:reason(1000):openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:772:
```

Answer (score 0):

**Cause:**

Eventually I found that my ISP had updated its so-called `Kids Safe` security settings and was treating `admin.firebase.com` as a blocked file sharing site.

**Solution:**

I updated my settings in the `ISPs config`, so that access to firebase.com was always allowed.  Now firebase init, firebase list etc are working fine.